# ReactJS - Code only runs on first time only

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gsap

I'm currently in the process of learning ReactJS and Javascript in general. I have this problem where if I put some Javascript code in the file. it only runs once when I start the test server (or build) but after that it seems to be broken afterwards. I assume this is because of the way ReactJS works and how the Javascript might gets saved or cached? I hope someone can point me in the right direction since this problem occurs with every piece of code I try, below I will post my code. thanks in advance :)

```
import "./main.css";
import gsap from "gsap";



function Hero() {

let tl = gsap.timeline();
tl.from(".hero--image", { opacity: 0, scale: 0.4 });

  return (
    <div className="container hero--image shadow-sm h100 br">
      <div className="container d-flex h-100 h-md-0 text-reveal">
        <div className="col col-12 col-md-6 d-inline-flex">
          <div className="hero--padding py-md-0 hero--textbox text-white">
            <h1 className="text-left">Title</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
              accumsan in nisl ut hendrerit. Praesent dictum massa lectus, quis
              ullamcorper velit pharetra sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-12 col-md-6 d-none d-md-inline-flex">
          <div className="hero--logo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Check you browser console and see what output is there.

Comment: `"it only runs"` - what is "it"?

Comment: @ArashdeepSingh the console only gives this as a return: GSAP target .hero--image not found. (but the .hero--image class does exist - because it works on first load)

Comment: @MauriceNino this part of the code ```let tl = gsap.timeline();
tl.from(".hero--image", { opacity: 0, scale: 0.4 })``` where the .hero--image class fades and scales in using the gsap libary

Comment: You edited it after posting, to include it in the component code. Why did that change? Also it is a linear animation as it seems. Why should it run again? What are the conditions for it to run again?

Comment: @MauriceNino, yes you are right, I accidentally put the wrong version of the code I have in there in the first place (I was just trying different things to get this to work). but to answer why it should run again; I don't know, that is what I'm trying to figure out here. there is probably no reason for the code to ever re-run, which is causing this problem. like I was saying, I'm new to this so I guess there is an overall concept I'm not getting and because of that I don't know how to adjust the code so its runs every time you visit the page, instead of only the first time you visit.

Comment: Unless gsap saves something in the local storage (which I highly doubt), it should run on every page load, or more specifically on every component mount. How are you testing the "page visit"?

Comment: @MauriceNino i made a little screen recording of how im working, hopefully this clears things up > https://www.daanblom.com/screencap.mp4 

also it does not seem to have anything to do with gsap in particular because with other pieces of code i tried the same thing happend actually, thank for looking!

Comment: Ah, I see, that's weird. Have you tried what's written in the following post? https://greensock.com/forums/topic/27802-gsap-animation-is-breaking-on-refresh-reactjs/

Comment: @MauriceNino well, that definitely pointed me in the right direction, this was in Babel so had to figure out how to make it work in React but it was possible to with useRef and useState. i changed the code to the following to get it to work: ```import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Hero() {
  const boxRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.from([boxRef.current], {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 10,
      duration: 1,
      rotation: 0.001,
      delay: 1,
    });
  });``` and then adding ref={boxRef} to the div that needs the effect

Comment: @MauriceNino highly appreciate your help and time!!!

Comment: No problem, glad this helped you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed code

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./main.css";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Hero() {
  const boxRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.from([boxRef.current], {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 10,
      duration: 1,
      rotation: 0.001,
      delay: 1,
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="container hero--image shadow-sm h100 br">
      <div className="container d-flex h-100 h-md-0 text-reveal">
        <div className="col col-12 col-md-6 d-inline-flex">
          <div
            ref={boxRef}
            className="hero--padding py-md-0 hero--textbox text-white"
          >
            <h1 className="text-left">Title</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
              accumsan in nisl ut hendrerit. Praesent dictum massa lectus, quis
              ullamcorper velit pharetra sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-12 col-md-6 d-none d-md-inline-flex">
          <div className="hero--logo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

Comment: This answer could be better if it included an explanation of why using useEffect/useRef is needed.